# How to add a function to Object's named property with correct context in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, this

I have a working piece of code as below:

```
let pageParams = {
  data: { todos: [], desc: '' }
}

pageParams.onLoad = function () {
  //I am trying to encapsulate this to a standalone function and 
  // make it generic, instead of hard coding the 'this.addTodo=XXX'
  const evProducer = {
    start: listener => {
      //Here, I am adding a named property function
      this.addTodo = ev => {
        listener.next(ev.detail.value)
      }
    },
    stop: ()=>{}
  }
  const input$ = xs.create(evProducer)
  input$.compose(debounce(400)).subscribe({
    next: val => console.log(val)
  })
}
```

The code works and now I am going to do some refactor work, i.e. move the logic out of this onLoad function. So I move the logic to another module

```
let xsCreator = {}


xsCreator.fromEvent = function(handler){
  const evProducer = {
    start: listener => {
      handler = ev => listener.next(ev.detail.value)
    },
    stop: () => {}
  }
  return xs.create(evProducer)
}
```

And in the previous onLoad function becomes the following:

```
pageParams.onLoad = function () {
  xs.fromEvent(this.addTodo).subscribe(blablabla)
}
```

but it does not work. I guess I might use apply/call/bind to make this work, but don't know how to. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks very similar to the `this` issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458611/javascript-es6-class-level-array-not-pushing-objects - try `pageParams.onLoad =  () => {` how do you trigger the non-standard onLoad?

Comment: using arrow function does not work, my problem is that I got the pageParams did not register the this.addTodo to its named property

Comment: I am working based a run-time library, the runtime will detect the onLoad and call it then

Comment: Should that not be onload? and is `this` here the `this` you think it is? `xs.fromEvent(this.addTodo)`

Comment: no, `this` here is pageParams,  at least I expected

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, I should use Object.defineProperty to add a named property for object.

```
xsCreator.fromInputEvent = (srcObj, propertyName) => {
  const evProducer = {
    start: (listener) => {
      Object.defineProperty(
      srcObj, 
      propertyName, 
      {value: ev => listener.next(ev.detail.value)})
    },
    stop: () => {}
  }
  return xs.create(evProducer)
}
```